# How to auto decline Windows Rollup Previews on WUSU

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-update

With MS' new monthly Rollup Updates, I would like to avoid installing the "Preview Quality Rollups" that are sent out at the end of the month.

I am currently using a win 2008r2 running Windows Server Update Service (WSUS) to control how updates are installed.  My desktops are in a Computer Group that auto approves all the updates and my servers are set to manually approve.  Is there any way of filtering out the Preview Updates specifically? It would be nice if they added a new Classification, but I don't see one.

Thanks in advance,

Jonathan